# GCM Drops Messages

Tags: php, android, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I have a demo of gcm working here: http://leobee.com/android/push/login/gcm/updateusers.php

If you refresh the page, you will see a new random number. Only 1 out of 4 page refreshes delivers a message to gcm.   Is this normal or is there some tweeks to the code I can use?

The page is not being cached.

code:

```
<?php


require_once '../include/DB_Functions.php';


// get database access
$db = new DB_Functions();

header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");

//api key 
$apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$result;

//array for phones connected to this service
$registrationIDs = array();


$randomNum=rand(10,100);


echo "this is updateusers".$randomNum;
$_POST['message']="updateusers".$randomNum;
if (isset($_POST['message']) && $_POST['message'] != ''){   

echo "<br>if (isset) updateusers".$randomNum;
    // Message to be sent
    $id= ''.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['server_id'])).'';
    $new_message= ''.mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['message'])).'';


    // get client registration IDs
    $query ="SELECT * FROM GoogleCloudMsg";

    $queryresult=mysql_query($query);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult)){
    echo "<br>While loop updateusers".$randomNum;
        $regId=$row['GCMPhoneRegisteredId'];

        array_push($registrationIDs,$regId);

}



// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$fields;

if(!$id || $id==""){

    $fields = 
array(
'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs, 
'data' => array("message" => $new_message), 
'delay_while_idle'=> false,
'collapse_key'=>"".$randomNum.""
);

    echo "<br> id is blank updateusers".$randomNum;

}else{

$fields = 
array(
'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs, 
'data' => array("message" =>$new_message,"server_id"=>$id), 
 'delay_while_idle' => 'false',
'collapse_key'=>"".$randomNum.""
);

echo "<br>id exists updateusers".$randomNum;

}
$headers = array('Authorization: key=' . $apiKey, 'Content-Type: application/json');

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;

}

echo "<br>mysql close updateusers".$randomNum;
 mysql_close();


?>
```

Comment: The site doesn't always print the returned JSON: take a look at it as Google put error codes and things in it of there is a problem (such as an incorrect API key or if you're sending too many requests, etc.)

Also are you sending the data in JSON or as an encoded form?

Comment: Actually judging from that while loop you may indeed be sending too many messages. GCM required you implement exponential backoff. Try adding a `LIMIT 1` to the SQL and see if it works. Otherwise look at the returned JSON, as I mentioned above.

Comment: yes, I'm encodeing them curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

Comment: LIMIT 1 only brings back one phone id, I'd need all of them to fill out the array and send on to GCM

Comment: the backoff in the Documentation refers to registrating to and out of GCM service. Not to the messages. I'm sending one message to 4 phone ids. That is not a lot.

Comment: But you may be sending them too quickly. Did it send 100% of the time with the `LIMIT 1`? A better way would be to use JSON and have multiple IDs to send to (see `registration_ids` http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#request)

Comment: I am getting the  same results with `LIMIT 1`.I'll checkout backoff again...

Comment: Also check out the GCM troubleshooting http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#response and try the `curl` request they outline in it

Comment: The amount of time between request doesn't matter. I've waited 5 minutes between request and I still get "fail" error from curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two ways to fix this.

1. generate and install an CA certificate.
2. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

not verifying the host.

Comment: Another reason for this problem is the CA certificate from Yahoo Hosting. It is rented through a third party and so it does not exist in your webspace or on your account. I had to buy hosting and certificate thru Godaddy. The script works fine now.